# Keyboard shortcut for Safari stop loading webpage button

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, web-browsing

While a page is loading, I somewant to stop it midway once the important bits have been loaded, and I don't want to continue loading the other unnecessary stuff on the page. This is especially the case with pages which are full of sidebars, images, scripts, etc.

I can click the little cross button in the address bar, but is there a keyboard shortcut for it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding <kbd>esc</kbd> can stop many pages from loading/ progressing.

You can also disable JavaScript in Develop menu (safari preferences → advanced, enable it) if such popups are asking for login etc. This works only if the content loads without JS, or before banner is added.

You can install content blockers, ad blockers which can zap the troubling elements from webpages.